# Preventing auto input on form field Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, bots

I have noticed something on a number of websites now where auto filling form fields is not accepted by the form.

take for example [Spotify Register](https://www.spotify.com/us/signup/), if you change the vaule using:

```
document.getElementById("email").value = "mail@maily.com"
```

you will notice upon blur the field will be wiped and error.

I really liked this and was curious about it so i played with some code and tried all sorts of key events with ups and downs and change and no matter what i tried it would always be wiped and soon as i focus elsewhere.

Can anyone advise me how this works and how i might use it in my own development to prevent automatic form submission.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the value like this `document.getElementById("email").value = "mail@maily.com"` then `onchange` event will not be fired. You can code your `onchange` method in a way that when `onblur` is executed then it can check that flag of `onchange` if flag is `negative` which means `onchange` not fired and you can wipe the value.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Input Test</title>
  </head>
  <script>
    let isTyped = false;
    function handleChange() {
      isTyped = true;
    }
    function validate() {
      if (!isTyped) {
        document.getElementById("text").value = null;
      }
    }
  </script>
  <body>
    <input id="text" type="text" onchange="handleChange()" onblur="validate()" autofocus />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thats really interesting can it be countered?.

Comment: Hi @PoopyDoop , i have added some code you can prevent it.